# what to use instead of swippable table view cell in android?

Tags: mobile, android, ios

Currently i'm working on a project which has list items that include swippable table view cell.

Since this is so popular in ios and rarely used in android (only partly in google inbox app), I wonder if there is any suggestions that you could share.

here is a sample. the actions can be multiple too.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In android there's always the long-press gesture, the swipe in android is mostly used as a direct delete function. Perhaps you should read the guidelines for each platform first as this will explain the expected behaviour a user would have on said platform :-)